# Android: Get Current Position Using MediaExtractor & MediaCodec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I'm creating my own implementation of Media Player using the MediaCode, MediaExtractor and AudioTrack. I need to perform distortions on the decoded mp3 samples I read from locally stored audio files- hence the custom implementation. For this reason I need to implement my own `seekTo` and `getCurrentPosition` functions. However, I'm not sure how I would go about implementing the latter.

I could set up a listener to increment the position while playing but this sounds like a terrible idea and probably not accurate. What is the best way to do it? I am looking to support API level 16 or greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer came from using the MediaExtractor. Once the extractor has read sample data via the `extractor.readSampleData(...)` method, a sample has been loaded.

A subsequent call to `extractor.getSampleTime()` provides the current time in *microseconds*. Dividing that value by 1,000 gives the milisecond value. I store this variable as its read and it's the source for subsequent calls to my custom player's `getCurrentPosition()` method.

Comment: Are you using `extractor.getSampleTime()` in your `getCurrentPosition()` method?